# preserveAspectRatio does not seem to alter the svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have been reading a number of tutorials online about the viewBox attribute and aspect ratio and I am confused.

In the example below I have the first example where both the viewPort and the viewBox have an aspect ratio of `5:1`.  I then altered the viewBox attribute in the next image to be `2:1` while the viewport is `5:1`

```html
<svg width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 10" >
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>

<svg width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 10" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>
```

I have made the aspect ratio `2:1` and added the `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` which appears to do nothing.

Why has `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` done nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Stretching does not occur, as in both examples the same fixed value of the viewing window `viewport` - (`width = "500"`  `height = "100"`)

You must remove the fixed values of `viewport` -``` width = "500" `` height = "100" ```

If `viewport` is not specified, then the value of the browser window is set to 100%.
If `preserveAspectRatio` is not specified, then it defaults to `preserveAspectRatio = xMidYMid`

```css
.container
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" >
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>

<h2>Yes stretching</h2>
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

For adaptability, you can also specify `viewport` in percent `width = "50%"` `height = "50%"`

Comment: if there is no viewport width and height I don't quite get what width and height mean on the viewbox.  Also preserveAspectRatio appears to do nothing

Comment: @dagda1 If viewport is not specified, then the value of the browser window is set to 100%. If `preserveAspectRatio` is not specified, then it defaults to` preserveAspectRatio = xMidYMid`

Comment: @dagda1 For adaptability, you can also specify `viewport` in percent  `width = "50%"`  `height = "50%"`

Answer (score 1):

Your A.R. calculation is wrong.

The first SVG have the width set to **500**, height to **100** and the viewBox attribute set to **0 0 500 10**. That means that along the y-axis every coordinate unit will correspond to 10 pixels, but along the x-axis every coordinate unit will only correspond to 1 pixel. As you can see, the aspect ratio along the x-axis is **500 / 500 = 1** and along the y-axis is **100 / 10 = 10** . Aspect Ratio for first SVG is `(1,10)`

The second SVG have the width set to **500**, height to **100** and the viewBox attribute set to **0 0 50 10**. As you can see, the aspect ratio along the x-axis is **500 / 50 = 10** and along the y-axis is **100 / 10 = 10** . That means that along the x-axis and y-axis every coordinate unit will correspond to 10 pixels. So, Aspect Ratio for second SVG is `(10,10)`.

> If `preserveAspectRatio: xMinYMin meet` is set, the view box is scaled according to the smaller of the two aspect ratios. [Source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

But in your second SVG, the code does not work because the aspect ratios on the two axis are the same `(10,10)`.

To try how the code works, add it to the first SVG which has different aspect ratios.

```html
<h2>SVG does not have preserveAspectRatio option</h2>
<svg width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 10" >
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>

<h2>SVG have xMinYMin meet</h2>
<svg width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 500 10" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <circle r="25" cx="30" cy="30" fill="#f00" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" style="fill: transparent"></rect>
</svg>
```